# I am getting the error, "assigning to 'id avaudioplayerdelegate ' from incompatible type "gameViewController""

Tags: objective-c, audio

```
    -(void)playSound: (NSString*)sound 

{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound ofType:@"mp3"];

    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self; 
    [theAudio play];
    [AVAudioPlayer release];
}
```

everything still works, there's just an annoying error that might be causing a lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure `gameViewController` conforms to the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface gameViewController : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
.
.
.
@end
```

assuming that's the name of your class.

Comment: thanks. I'm new to coding. Do I put that in the header or implementation file?

Comment: That should go in your header file.

Comment: Sorry for the slip; I didn't mean to mess with your head.

Comment: the header already says    @interface gameViewController: UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate> so how would i add the audioplayer as well

Comment: <UIAccelerometerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, why must you declare the accelerometer and audioplayer there, but not other things? What classifies something as having to be declared there?

Comment: Not sure about UIAccelerometerDelegate, but if you look at the documentation for AVAudioPlayerDelegate, you'll see that its delegate property is `id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`. `id` is a generic reference for an Objective-C object, but the part that follows says the object must conform to the protocol specified between the angle brackets.